# How to change profile name in Meteor?

Tags: user-interface, meteor

I wonder how to change user profile information in Meteor. I created an application using the accounts-base package, so I can quickly manage all related stuff with user accounts. Which is really great.

In official docs it says:

> profile: an Object which (by default) the user can create and update with any data.

But how could I let the user to change it?

Regarding the same topic, using the `{{loginButtons}}` tag by default I get the following image when the user has logged in:

[image]

Is there any possibility to add `Change profile`, `Change email` or something similar?

Thanks

Comment: you have to write your own user profile feature, just use Meteor.users.update to update your collection.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For the moment `accounts-ui` doesn't have a change profile button built in, you have to make it manually.

For instance if you do

```
Meteor.users.update({_id:Meteor.user()._id}, {$set:{"profile.name":"Carlos"}})
```

You could change the screen in `accounts-ui` above you have to show a name instead of the email you would click to display the dialog above.

The email is a little bit tricker, you have to do this from the server since (in a meteor.methods/call perhaps) you can't modify the email stuff from the client, I would suggest adding a new email and having it verified instead of changing the existing email (since its also their login). Or having it **verified first** then changing it so as not to change someones email to something where they can't recover their password.

```
Meteor.users.update({_id:Meteor.user()._id}, {$addToSet:{"emails":{address:"newemail@newemail.com","verified":false}}});
```

Or if you want users to have one email they can change:

```
Meteor.users.update({_id:Meteor.user()._id}, {$set:{"emails":[{address:"newemail@newemail.com"}]});
```

Comment: You forgot the quotes in the Mongodb selector (around `profile.name`) in your first line of code, this should be : `Meteor.users.update({_id:Meteor.user()._id}, {$set:{"profile.name":"Carlos"}})`

Comment: ~~Where is the meteor mongodb url?~~ ahh this is in the browser gotcha oops thank you

Comment: This is out of date and no longer works, as Access denied is shown.

Comment: @Nick, This still works, see : https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/9fbea207d350334499e4218ff82c5928aa8dd0a9/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js#L1393-L1406. Something else is stopping it working based on your app/configuration.

Comment: I guess I should be more clear this is my developer account. The user/profile name seems to be locked. Heck I can't even figure out how to delete the account.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474399/how-do-i-delete-a-meteor-developer-account

Comment: @Nick I'm not sure about the relevance of the question to this answer. Meteor dev accounts are hosted by MDG on meteor.com

Comment: Sorry about the relevance but I got here as I want to delete a dead account of mine. Which appears to be impossible at the moment in doing it myself.

Answer (score 0):

To expand this answer it is better to put this code into [(Validated)](https://github.com/meteor/validated-method) Meteor method.

- use [CallPromiseMixin](https://github.com/Didericis/callpromise-mixin) to call this method with async/await syntax on frontend
- use [simpl-schema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simpl-schema) to validate username argument

```js
// imports/api/methods.js

const NO_SPECIAL_CHARACTERS_REGEX = /^[^`~!@#$%^&*()_|+=?;:'"<>{}\[\]\\/]*$/;

export const updateProfileName = new ValidatedMethod({
    name: 'users.updateProfileName',
    mixins: [CallPromiseMixin],
    validate: new SimpleSchema({
        name: { type: String, regEx: NO_SPECIAL_CHARACTERS_REGEX, min: 1, max: 50 },
    }).validator(),
    run({ name }) {
        if (!this.userId) {
            throw new Meteor.Error('User needs to be signed in to call this method');
        }
        return Meteor.users.update({ _id: this.userId }, { $set: { 'profile.name': name } });
    },
});
```

then on frontend

```js
// imports/ui/changeName.js

Template.changeName.events({
    // ...
    
    async 'submit #change-name-form'(event, instance) {
        event.preventDefault();
        try {
            await updateProfileName.callPromise({ name: instance.$('#profile-name').val() });
        } catch (e) {
            // do something with the error
        }
    },
});
```