# How do I delete a meteor developer account?

Tags: meteor

I ended up with two meteor developer accounts due to fiddling around with little understanding when I was just getting started.  How do I delete one of the accounts now?  I know this is a simple question, but I have searched the command line help, docs and manual with no success.

Comment: I visited https://www.meteor.com/account-settings and couldn't find a way to delete my account so I suppose this is not possible at the moment.

Comment: This is ridiculous that this has not been solved in a year.

Answer (score 3):

- Go to http://meteor.com/contact
- Select "Meteor Account Support"
- Fill out the required fields and write a message asking to delete your account.
- Wait several days, you may get further instructions to verify you own the account.

There are certain conditions where an account cannot be deleted:

- have published packages
- have app deployments
- active login tokens

In my case, what I really wanted to do was convert an account to an organization, and for this the steps are similar:

- Go to http://meteor.com/contact
- Select "Meteor Account Support"
- Fill out the required fields and write a message asking to convert your account to an organization

  - Mention the old account name you want converted
  - Mention the name of the new account that will own this organization
- Wait several days for a response
- At this point you will be asked to move the email address from the old account to the new account and verify it.

  - Add a new email address to the old account, verify it and make it the primary email address
  - Delete the original email address from the old account
  - Add that email address to your new account and verify it
- Go [back](https://meteor.zendesk.com/hc/en-us) or reply to the email and let them know you did this.
- Some magic will happen and hopefully the name of the old account will appear as an organization in your new account.

<strike>I found [this issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3166) that recommends emailing `contact@meteor.com`.</strike> (no longer used)

Some people suggested tweeting at some of the [people of Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/people) to hurry things along as well.

Comment: Good edit, I almost flagged this answer until I saw the edit.

Comment: Thanks. I'm planning on updating this until something works.

Comment: The page has a contact at the bottom that you can use.